# ¿Eliminar etiqueta [mssql]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Revisando, ví tres preguntas únicamente con la etiqueta [mssql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mssql), todas tenían que ver con [sql-server](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). Modifiqué las tres para que apunte a esta última. ¿Vale la pena que además eliminemos [mssql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mssql)?

Comment: nótese que quemar = ponerlo en la lista negra. No sé si querrás esto o bien que se asocie con una ya existente.

Comment: @fedorqui, la duda existencial que tengo y que motiva mi pregunta es: si [mssql] es sinónimo de [sql-server] y hay preguntas solo con [mssql] de etiqueta, ¿la búsqueda por [sql-server] las encontrará?

Comment: Sí, al ser sinónimas se listan juntas bajo el nombre de la etiqueta que se defina como principal

Comment: Me explico: los sinónimos están en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms y ahora mismo no hay ninguno. Si miramos una que tiene como [tag:base-de-datos] la lista aparece en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/base-de-datos/synonyms Una de ellas es [tag:database] y que sean sinónimas consiste en que si a una pregunta le editas las etiquetas y empiezas a escribir "datab..." te recomendará "base-de-datos", indicando que son lo mismo. Haz la prueba, se explica mejor viéndolo :)

Comment: Aclarado @fedorqui gracias, creo que no tiene sentido entonces la eliminación de la etiqueta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Por qué no se hace un sinónimo que apunte a la etiqueta sql-server?

En el sitio en inglés se tienen los siguientes sinónimos: mssql, ms-sql-server & sql-srever

Comment: Si, de hecho creo que [mssql] ya es sinónimo, pero mi duda pasa a la hora del comentario que le hice recién a fedorqui